# Unable to click after trying all the ways in getting xpath

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I am unable to click and have tried all the ways in getting `x-path` and even though my script is passing, still it is not clicking in my device(real android phone)! Using appium and selenium.
Is t because of two spans(see the image below)?  I Want to click on `MINT_1150`!!!
Can someone please help?

[image]

UIAutomator Image for the same is here :

[image]

Comment: <span class="archive-icon MINT"/>
<span class="archive-name">MINT_1150</span>

Comment: <div class="x-list-item-first x-list-header-wrap x-list-item-last x-list-footer-wrap x-list-item x-stretched x-list-item-tpl x-list-item-relative" id="ext-simplelistitem-1" style="min-height: 42px !important;">
<div class="x-unsized x-list-disclosure" id="ext-component-4"/>
<div class="x-innerhtml" id="ext-element-39">
<div>
<span class="archive-icon MINT"/>
<span class="archive-name">MINT_1150</span>

Comment: Could you try and share a possible screenshot from appium inspector for the same element.

Comment: I have trouble in connecting appium inspector, i dono y!!  But, i am using uiautomator and those element values also seem to be not working!!

Comment: It would be good to see a screenshot from UIAutomator itself with these elements in the hierarchy.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RHXmE.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RHXmE.png

Comment: I have tried with selenium ide, instead of click cmd i tried with clickAt cmd and it worked. id=ext-component-4 in (0,0). Please help me in converting  this command in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are pointing to a wrong element here. Still keep a note of these two things :

1. Make sure you are *switching the context* to WEBVIEW for handling any automated case on this screen since its a webview inside the application.

   ```
   Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
   for (String contextName : contextNames) {
       System.out.println(contextName);
       if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
           driver.context(contextName);
       }
   }
   ```
2. **IF** point 1 is taken care of, try and access the element as

   ```
   WebElement yourElement = findElement(By.class("<classname>")); //to access the element
   yourElement.click(); //click on that element
   ```

**Note** : Also make sure the `yourElement` inside the application should be *clickable*.

*Edit* : In your case you can access the element as follow :

```
WebElement yourElement = findElement(By.id("ext-component-4")); //to access the element
yourElement.click(); //perform click
```

*Edit2* :

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(tElement).moveByOffset(0, 0).perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
action.click().build().perform(); // build the action and perform it as well
```

Comment: Hw can i switch the context to webview?

Comment: I also checked its a clickable!

Comment: @user2788966 : added a relevant java code to switch context to webview

Comment: Do i have any issue becoz it contains two spans inside div?

Comment: @user2788966 : no that does not seem to be causing any troubles here.

Comment: @user2788966 : from the screenshot its clear to access elements in this view you need to switch context as stated in the first point and then perform your action

Comment: I have tried with selenium ide, instead of click cmd i tried with clickAt cmd and it worked. id=ext-component-4 in (0,0). Please help me in converting  this command in selenium.

Comment: @user2788966 : added as an edit to the answer with `id = "ext-component-4"`

Comment: problem is click() is not working, we need to use clickAt command with coordinates!! I am struggling here only. no issue with locators.

Comment: i guess you are working with overlapped layouts and are ending up using incorrect layout to try and perform actions like click etc. Using coordinates work in a different way and therefore are able to perform the desired action.

Comment: WebElement tElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-component-4"));
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    
    action.moveToElement(tElement).moveByOffset(0, 0).perform();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    action.click();

Comment: @user2788966 : updated the code in Edit 2 in answer, you need to build and perform the `Actions`

Comment: Again script is passing, but it is not clicking in device!!

Answer (score 0):

We wont be able to verify the xpath without you posting it with complete HTML.

But for this case it would be simple to use the css selector to select the particular element instead of XPath. The below selector should select the element that you are looking for.

> '#ext-element-39 .archive-name'

I dont know about appium but using C# selenium we will be able to do like below

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector('#ext-element-39 .archive-name'))
```

There should be similar method in appium also.

One more option is you can use google chrome to get the correct xpath. right click the node and choose Copy Xpath

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: have you tried exact css selector that i have used? Or with a different selector ? Also Can you please post your code ?

Comment: Used as u mentioned and also this one:

Comment: #ext-element-39 > div > span.archive-name

Comment: @user2788966 I have added an image to get xpath from chrome dev tools. Can you try this ?

Comment: ya i am using the same to get css selector and xpath!! When i use the same xpath which i got, script is passing, but it is not clicking in my device!! please suggest...

Comment: I have tried with selenium ide, instead of click cmd i tried with clickAt cmd and it worked. id=ext-component-4 in (0,0). Please help me in converting  this command in selenium.